# Recognizing missing values and return a list with these values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I am quite new to coding and I have done a very small Pandas course at work recently and a part of this course was to think about a project where we would like to improve something. I want to be able to recognise the missing values in a table from a CSV or Excel file and then make a list of these missing values.
An example of imported CSV file:

> Company    2016    2015    2014    2013    2012    2011    2010
>
> AAPL US    31  NaN 21.0    3.0 NaN 80.0    7
>
> MSFT US    72  8.0 67.0    NaN 93.0    30.0    37
>
> SNAP US    51  NaN NaN 7.0 33.0    16.0    44
>
> FB US  49  56.0    33.0    97.0    NaN NaN 98

Into:

> AAPL US, 2015, 2012
>
> MSFT US, 2013
>
> SNAP US, 2015, 2014
>
> FB US, 2012, 2011

I understand how to count them and etc, but I want to see a finalized list in some sort.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), check `NaN`s by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) and last generate `list`s by `apply` with filtering:

```
df = (df.set_index('Company')
        .isnull()
        .apply(lambda x : x.index[x].tolist(), 1)
        .reset_index(name='val'))
print (df)
   Company           val
0  AAPL US  [2015, 2012]
1  MSFT US        [2013]
2  SNAP US  [2015, 2014]
3    FB US  [2012, 2011]
```

Or if want `string`s:

```
df = df.set_index('Company')
s = np.where(df.isnull(), ['{}, '.format(x) for x in df.columns], '')
df = pd.Series([''.join(x).strip(', ') for x in s], index=df.index).reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
   Company         val
0  AAPL US  2015, 2012
1  MSFT US        2013
2  SNAP US  2015, 2014
3    FB US  2012, 2011
```

Comment: Thanks! 
I have stumbled upon another problem; when my periods go from yearly (2016) to "2016 Q1" I get an error. Is there a way around this or would I need to clean the data e.g. "2016 1" ?

Comment: I think if need convert periodindex to strings need `df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y %q')`.